# Exercise 1.5.8 from Robin Hartshorne's Deformation Theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

I don't know how to solve part (a) of exercise 1.5.8 in Robin Hartshorne's book Deformation Theory 1.5.8 (page 42):

> Consider the Hilbert scheme of zero-dimensional closed subschemes
> of $\mathbb{P}^4_k$ of length $8$, the field $k$ is algebraically closed. There is one component of dimension $32$
> that has a nonsingular open subset corresponding to sets of eight
> distinct points. We will exhibit another component containing a nonsingular open
> subset of dimension $25$.

> (a) Let $R=k[x,y,z,w]$, let $\mathfrak{m}$ be a maximal ideal in
> this ring, and let $I=V+\mathfrak{m}^3$, where
> $V$ is a $7$-dimensional subvector space of
> $\mathfrak{m}^2/\mathfrak{m}^3$. Let $B=R/I$, and
> let $Z= \operatorname{Spec}(B)$ be the associated closed subscheme of
> $\mathbb{A}^4 \subset \mathbb{P}^4$.
> Show that the set of all such $Z$, as the point of its support
> ranges over $\mathbb{P}^4$, forms an irreducible $25$-dimensional
> subset of the
> Hilbert scheme $H=\operatorname{Hilb}^8(\mathbb{P}^4)$.

How can I show that this subscheme of the Hilbert scheme is irreducible? I have no idea even how to start. Is there a general strategy how to deal with that kind of questions to show that certain subscheme of a moduli space is irreducible? Clearly it suffice to construct an irreducible open dense subscheme sitting inside it, but I not see how to manage it in this exercise.

Comment: Isn't it isomorphic to an appropriate Grassmannian?

Comment: @YosemiteStan: yes, we can surely construct 'by hand' a map of sets
$\text{Gr}(7, \mathfrak{m}^2/\mathfrak{m}^3) \to \operatorname{Hilb}^8(\mathbb{P}^4)(k)$ sending subvector space 
$V \subset \mathfrak{m}^2/\mathfrak{m}^3$ to $Z \subset \mathbb{P}^4$, a point of the Hilbert scheme. But can we prolonge it naturally to an closed embedding
$\mathcal{Gras}(7, \dim_k \mathfrak{m}^2/\mathfrak{m}^3) \subset
\operatorname{Hilb}^8(\mathbb{P}^4)$ of schemes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment also indicates, consider the Grassmannian $ Gr_3(\operatorname{Sym}^2 \Omega_{\mathbb{P}^4} ) $ where the vector bundle $ \operatorname{Sym}^2 \Omega_{\mathbb{P}^4} $ has fiber $ m_p^2/m_p^3 $ over a point $ p \in \mathbb{P}^4 $. Then there is a morphism $ Gr_3(\operatorname{Sym}^2 \Omega_{\mathbb{P}^4} ) \rightarrow Hilb^8(\mathbb{P}^4) $ and it suffices to give it by specifying it on $ \mathbb{C} $-valued points. By the universal property, a point in $ Gr_3(\operatorname{Sym}^2 \Omega_{\mathbb{P}^4} ) ( \mathbb{C} ) $ is given by a point in $ \mathbb{P}^4 $ along with a $ 3 $-dimensional quotient $ \operatorname{Sym}^2 \Omega_{\mathbb{P}^4}|_p = m_p^2 / m_p^3 \rightarrow Q \rightarrow 0 $, or equivalently a $ 7 $-dimensional subspace, which in turn gives the appropriate length $ 8 $ subscheme of $ \mathbb{P}^4 $.

It only remains to see that $Gr_3(\operatorname{Sym}^2 \Omega_{\mathbb{P}^4} ) $ is $ 25 $-dimensional and irreducible.

Comment: I'm getting a bit confused with your second statement. Do you claim that every
morphism $X \to Hilb^8(\mathbb{P}^4)$ from arbitrary scheme $X$ 
can be defined by specifying it on $\mathbb{C}$-valued points, or
is it here a special intrinsic feature of the space 
$Gr_3(\operatorname{Sym}^2 \Omega_{\mathbb{P}^4} )$ that in order
to establish a map 
$Gr_3(\operatorname{Sym}^2 \Omega_{\mathbb{P}^4} ) \rightarrow Hilb^8(\mathbb{P}^4)$
it suffice to specify it on $\mathbb{C}$-valued points?

Comment: Or do you mean above that if $X$ is any scheme with the property 
that any $\mathbb{C}$-point of it can be intrinsically identified
with a point of $Hilb^8(\mathbb{P}^4)$, then this already suffice to obtain
a map $X \to Hilb^8(\mathbb{P}^4)$?

Comment: Any morphism from a *variety* $ X $ to $ Hilb $ can be understood by understanding it on its geometric points. This is in Hartshorne (his original book) as the t-functor in chapter 2.

Comment: Next, the dimension count is easy since every fiber of $Gr_3(\operatorname{Sym}^2 \Omega_{\mathbb{P}^4} ) \to \mathbb{P}^4$ is $Gr_3(m_p^2/m_p^3)$ and has therefore dimension $(10-3)3=21$ plus the dimnsion of the base, so $25$. But why is $Gr_3(\operatorname{Sym}^2 \Omega_{\mathbb{P}^4} )$ irreducible? Over affine charts $\mathbb{A}^4 \subset \mathbb{P}^4$ it becomes the Grassmanian over affine space $\operatorname{Sym}^2 \Omega_{\mathbb{A}^4}= \mathbb{A}^N$, which is irreducible. Does it follow from this that $Gr_3(\operatorname{Sym}^2 \Omega_{\mathbb{P}^4} ) \to \mathbb{P}^4$ is irreducible?

Comment: Very important result: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579527/use-irreducible-fibers-to-show-x-is-irreducible

Comment: I think the irreducibility can be deduced more elementary. A scheme
$X$ is irreducible if and only if it admits an open 
cover $X= \bigcup_i U_i$ by finitely many open irreducible 
subschemes $U_i$ with the property that the pairwise intersections
$U_i \cap U_j$ are non trivial and irreducible. Over every open chart $\mathbb{A}^4 \subset \mathbb{P}^4$
the $Gr_3(\operatorname{Sym}^2 \Omega_{\mathbb{P}^4} )$
restricts to honest Grassmannian over affine space
$\operatorname{Sym}^2 \Omega_{\mathbb{A}^4}= \mathbb{A}^N$, which is irreducible.

Comment: Taking any finite open affine cover of $\mathbb{P}^4$ we obtain a finite open cover of $Gr_3(\operatorname{Sym}^2 \Omega_{\mathbb{P}^4} )$ satisfying the condition above.

Comment: Yes, that’s true. Since I was just looking for a general reference for your question, I put in that link.